# How to this Resolve Merge Conflict in Github Desktop

Tags: git, github, github-desktop

when I try to pull to a branch I receive this error:

> error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten
> by merge:   filename.txt Please commit your changes or stash them
> before you merge. Aborting....

I can easily resolve this message in the console. I add the file and then commit it eg.:

```
git add filename.txt
git commit filename.txt -m "Committing file".
```

My question is, how can I resolve the same issue using Github Desktop? I know that the command line is the best tool for resolving git merges, but I really need a solution to resolve the same problem in Github Desktop without having to use the command line.

Thanks.

Comment: [How to commit code to a Git repository with GitHub Desktop](https://learn.sourcegraph.com/how-to-commit-code-to-a-git-repository-with-github-desktop)